# Positioning text

Tags: html, position

I want to be able to move the text "The best products. At the best prices." below keep it simple but everytime i use padding it creates a white box behind it. The only way to fix this is to use position absolute but then it doesnt seem to be responsive when i resize the website

```
.TextTop{
position: absolute;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-left: 250px;

font-size: 20px;
font-style: arial;
color: darkblue;
```

}

I want to be able to have a responsive text so when the webpage is changed in size it will move with it. While being able to place my text exactly where it needs to be without interfering with other things on the webpage.
I am new and thankyou very mmuch

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is

```
margin: Npx
```

Instead of

```
padding: Npx
```